# Multi-Hierarchy IDisposable Implementation for DbContext in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Base class:

```
public abstract class Repository : IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed;
    private DbContext _context;
    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void SetSomething()
    {
        //...Access the database and set something for tracing
        _context.Database.SqlQuery(....);
    }

    public void UnSetSomething()
    {
        //...Access the database and cancel something for tracing
        _context.Database.SqlQuery(....);
    }

    #region Object Disposal
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~Repository()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            // free other managed objects that implement IDisposable only
            if (_context != null)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
                _context = null;
            }
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Sub Class:

```
public class ScheduleRepository : Repository
{
    private AppContext _context;

    public ScheduleRepository(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        _context = (AppContext)context;
    }

    #region Object Disposal
    bool _disposed;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~ScheduleRepository()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            // free other managed objects that implement IDisposable only
            if (_context != null)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
                _context = null;
            }
        }

        _disposed = true;

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Logic Class:

```
public class ScheduleFacade
{
    private ScheduleRepository _repository;
    public ScheduleFacade()
    {
        _repository = new ScheduleRepository(AppContext.Create());
    }

    public ScheduleSetting GetScheduleById(string scheduleId)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scheduleId))
        {
            _repository.SetSomething();

            ScheduleSetting settings = _repository.GetScheduleById(scheduleId);

            _repository.UnSetSomething();

            return LoadScheduleSettings(settings);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The scheduleId parameter cannot be empty.");
        }
    }

    private ScheduleSetting LoadScheduleSettings(ScheduleSetting settings)
    {
        //...code ....
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to implement `IDisposable` on an abstract class implementation? This is not following the DRY principals like it should but I am unclear how to do this properly.

I want to make sure that I am cleaning up my `DbContext` appropriately.

EDIT: It appears that more information is needed to clarify what I am doing and why I am passing in DbContext in the constructor (I have added more code above to please re-read).  I needed the DbContext in the abstract class to access the database and do some work.  Isn't this how I would use an abstract class that is shared among multiple sub classes and thus allowing me to adhere to the DRY principal and centralize future maintenance?

How would I pass the DbContext to the abastract class if I dont pass it through the contstructor (method injection comes to mind but that would require that devs of future repositories might forget to pass the context to the base class).

Comment: Why not just make `context` protected instead of having a _different_ field in the base class?  Then you don't need to override any of the base class dispose functions. If fact, you're _not_ overriding them right now, you're _hiding_ them.

Comment: I would not implment `IDisposable` on your repositories because the only thing you're disposing (`context`) is not being created by your repository, it is given to it instead.  Not all classes conform to this, but a good practice to have the thing that creates a disposable to be the one to dispose of it.

Comment: To add to Matthew's correct point, the repository should _not_ hold a reference to the context - rather it should create a context for each request, so there's no need to make your repository disposable.

Comment: @Matthew I have updated my question.  Please re-read.

Comment: First try using generics , public abstract class Repository<T> : IDisposable where T : DbContext

Comment: Are you using an IoC framework?

Comment: @Matthew, not quite yet.  I am still learning IoC frameworks and how to use them appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking for generic disposable abstract class take a look at the below class , but as @Matthew and @D Stanley said ...the repository should initialize the context each time.

```
public abstract class DisposableObject : IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public virtual bool IsDisposed
    {
        get { return _disposed; }
    }

    protected void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().FullName);
        }
    }

    protected void CheckDisposed(string err)
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().FullName, err);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            OnDispose(disposing);
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }

    protected abstract void OnDispose(bool disposing); // this for the implementor to dispose their items

    ~DisposableObject()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

}
```

for your implementation of the repository pattern it will be like that:

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IDisposable where T : DbContext
{
    private bool _disposed;
    private T _context;
    public Repository(T context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected T Context { get { return _context; } }

    public void SetSomething()
    {
        //...Access the database and set something for tracing
        // _context.Database.SqlQuery(....);
    }

    public void UnSetSomething()
    {
        //...Access the database and cancel something for tracing
        //_context.Database.SqlQuery(....);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (_context != null)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
                _context = null;
            }

            OnDispose(disposing);
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }

    // this for the implementor to dispose their items but not the context because it's already disposed from the base class
    protected abstract void OnDispose(bool disposing); 

    ~Repository()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

so in you Schedule Repository do it like that

```
public class ScheduleRepository : Repository<AppContext>
{

    public ScheduleRepository()
        :base(new AppContext())
    {

    }
    public Schedule GetById(int id) { 
        this.Context.Schedules. (....) // blah blah
    }

    protected override void OnDispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // if you are working with any thing that you must free it up
        // do it here, but not the context
    }
}
```

Edit::::

you logic class will look like that

```
public class ScheduleFacade
{
    private ScheduleRepository _repository;
    public ScheduleFacade()
    {
        _repository = new ScheduleRepository();
    }

    public ScheduleSetting GetScheduleById(string scheduleId)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scheduleId))
        {
            _repository.SetSomething();

            ScheduleSetting settings = _repository.GetScheduleById(scheduleId);

            _repository.UnSetSomething();

            return LoadScheduleSettings(settings);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The scheduleId parameter cannot be empty.");
        }
    }

    private ScheduleSetting LoadScheduleSettings(ScheduleSetting settings)
    {
        //...code ....
    }
}
```

so it won't depend on EF

Comment: You identify another question on this implementation.  In your code you have `base(new AppContext())` and then you use `this.Context.Schedules`.  I dont see a private variable/field containing `this.Context` that you instantiated in your ctor.  Can you explain?

Comment: In the base Repository I have a  ctor which take a T where T:DBContext, and to use this context in the drived class (ScheduleRepository) I just created a protected property in the Repository Base so that I can access the context 'protected T Context { get { return _context; } }'

Comment: What I mean is the usage of `this.Context.Schedules` in the sub class.  I see you create a `new AppContext()` in the ctor for the base class but how are you using that newly instantiated context in the sub class?  Do I need to create a new context in the sub class too?

Comment: this.Context.Schedules ... will use the one which u instantiated in the ctor new AppContext() because it will be inherited from the base class ... by the way Schedules is a name which I wrote may be you have another property name in the AppContext class which refer to the Schedule table in the DB

Comment: Ah. I forgot about "inheritance".

Comment: Ok.  With this implementation (which I really like) I am required to add Entity Framework in my business layer because of how it all works.  I would prefer not to reference the Entity Framework in that layer if possible.  My ScheduleFacade (business layer) instantiates ScheduleRepository (data layer).  Your thoughts?

Comment: check the upadte in the answer

Comment: Hmm.  I am getting `The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework,...`.  I would hate to have to "wrap" ScheduleRepository in another class.  That would be a code smell....  Maybe I need to create a factory that will produce a ScheduleRepository?